# MS Excel: Delete data in cells before first instance of character

Tags: excel

I have a column with data like

> 12 Frankton Rd, Queenstown 9300, New Zealand

I want to delete the information before the first comma, so the above becomes:

> Queenstown 9300, New Zealand

Of course if I use Find and Replace with `*,` this deletes the city name as well, so I can't use it.

Would anyone know how to achieve this?

Edit: After trying `=MID(B2,SEARCH(",",B2)+1,LEN(B2))`

[image]

Comment: His solution works. I even tested it with exactly your cells and input, including the +1 instead of +2, which just includes an extra leading space. Try doing just one address on a brand new empty workbook with that same formula and see if it works.

Comment: Try to write formula yourself instead of copy/paste

Comment: Also try selecting the cell with the formula, going to the "Formulas" ribbon tab, and selecting "Evaluate Formula." Step through and find out exactly which expression is giving the error.

Comment: @mock_blatt Weird, I copied the data accross to another sheet and it works fine. Odd.

Comment: Sometimes weird things can happen when copying and pasting. If you go to cell E2 in the non-working sheet, press F2, then press enter, does that happen to fix it? In any case, at least it works elsewhere.

Comment: @mock_blatt nah f2 doesnt do anything. Oh well. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that your address string is in cell `A2`. Then use this formula:

```
=MID(A2,SEARCH(",",A2)+2,LEN(A2))
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Thanks, but not luck

Comment: why? explain please

Comment: I'm not sure why, sorry. I just get the `#VALUE!` error.

Comment: I attached screenshot above

Comment: Weird. I've added mine above, All I did was modify the cell IDs.